# coding taps in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am new to jquery and i have a problem with selecting elements within it .
in this code i wanted to show and hide the "contents" div that have the same class of the li i click on . it should work like taps .
so i wrote this code but it's not working .

```js
$('.menu li').click(
  function() {
    var x = this.attr("class");
    $('.contents').children().hasClass(x).show();
    $('.contents').children().not(hasClass(x)).hide();
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu ">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="two"></li>
    <li class="three"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div class="one" style="background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="two" style="display: none; background-color:yellow"></div>
  <div class="three" style="display: none; background-color:orange"></div>
</div>
```

I'm actually not sure if this approach is even the right way to do it !

Comment: Your `<li>` class attribute values are all prefixed with a space. None of those attribute values match your `<div>` class attributes because of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with class attributes is that they can hold multiple, arbitrary values in any particular order. This makes them unsuitable for exact-match targeting.

I would instead give your `<div>` elements `id` attributes and use another attribute on the `<li>` elements to target those IDs. For example

```
<li class="one" data-target="one">
```

and

```
<div class="one" id="one">
```

and in your jQuery

```
$('.menu li[data-target]').on('click', function() {
  var targetId = this.getAttribute('data-target')
  $('.contents div').each(function() {
    $(this).toggle(this.id === targetId)
  })
})
```

See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

Comment: It worked ! thank you .
i've never known about that 'data-target' attribute